# Access all rows in table that is linked to another table

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables in SQLite. One is called `contacts` and the other is `phoneNumbers`. `phoneNumbers` is linked to `contacts` with `integer references`. Here is the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name text
);

CREATE TABLE phoneNumbers(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    homePhone text,
    contact_id INTEGER REFERENCES contacts(id)
);
```

My question is, how can I access all `homePhone` that is linked to `contacts (id)` 1?

Hope this is clear. If you have any questions, feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM phoneNumbers WHERE contact_id = 1` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Phil: Or even `SELECT homePhone FROM ...`.

Comment: @eggyal well yeah, it was just a quick question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have it:

```
SELECT homePhone 
FROM phoneNumbers 
JOIN contacts
ON homePhone.contact_id=contacts.id
WHERE contacts.id=1
```

And never use SELECT * :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639964/1919749

Comment: Why bother with the join?

Comment: Can you explain `JOIN` and `ON homePhone.contact_id=contacts.id`?

Comment: It binds the two tables together based upon the primary and foreign key relation. It is useful if you want to use additional columns from both tables.

Comment: @WorkSmarter Thats it!